# Change .png image on node.js with out any libs

Tags: javascript, node.js, png

I have got a .png image on my server and i need to change some pixels in it. How can i do that on node.js with out using any img librarys?  npm 'fs' is already installed
Need some examples or useful links.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using libraries? They have done all the hardwork for you and make your life a lot easier

Comment: You'll spend far more time writing a utility to do this than actually writing code to change the pixels without a library.

Comment: Yeah i know about libs advantage, but i cant use it for some reasons. I tried to google it, but didnt find any solution.

Comment: The solution for this problem is too intensive for a Stack Overflow answer. There's no native Node modules image parsing, so the most intensive part of a vanilla implementation would be parsing the imported file byte data into a readable and manipulatable format. I'd recommend looking into the PNG file format [PNG (Portable Network Graphics) Specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html). It's possible but difficult to implement a system for reading (parsing/decoding) and updating (encoding) the file's chunks by pixel. Good luck.